# Where am I located?

Tags: cipher, visual

Note: Not a true story

I am currently bored while idly thinking about how I got this job in VA. Sitting at a desk, I think about my work conditions while playing around on Inkscape. Below is the picture I drew.

[image]

Where am I located?

Hint 1:

> Look at my last puzzle. By the way I also incorporated a similar thing where things get harder the more you solve.

Hint 2:

> Look for what stands out (yeah it all stands out but some things "actually" stand out)

Pardon the image quality/content. If this one is also solved in under an hour I'll keep upping the difficulty.

Note: there will feel like a definitive answer when the puzzle is solved, but just to be clear, the answer will be directly related to six words, and the "HAIR" word shown isn't one of those. (it may be related to the puzzle however)

I keep feeling like I need to add more information but I'll stop editing for now and give you all a chance.

Edit: I know I said I would stop adding more hints, but I think one of my hints isn't fully accurate so I'll clarify and basically give up a major point.

> I say I made the image in Inkscape (I did, some of it), but if you know what Inkscape is, this image is obviously not of the traditional filetype. What is something that can be done in Inkscape puzzles?

Comment: give it at least 48hrs before adding another hint.

Comment: sure thing, I already added plenty more hints than necessary.

Comment: Question: (Maybe related to last hint?) Is it intentional that there is a "page" frame in the background (which doesn't fit). I thought so, but I'm else clueless about the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** - OK I think the location is now correct (message 6).

Message 1:

> The word HAIR means to look in the clown's green hair.  There is a 6x12 pixel block in the center with RGB colors 20-128-8, 19-128-8, 1-128-16, 5-128-0.  Converting to numbers of the alphabet (and ignoring 128) provides **T-H, S-H, A-P, E**.  So the message is "the shape" with the first "e" missing.

Message 2:

> So "the shape" is a star or a pentagram.  Interpreting this to be the larger star with pink shorts and assuming it is a Pythagorean pentagram, then its right arm (representing heat or the sun) is **pointing at the sun**.

Message 3:

> There is a block of 3 pixels adjacent to a lower left ray from the sun.  Their RGB colors are 3-15-0, 18-15-0, 5-18-0.  Converting to letters provides **C-O, R-O, E-R**, which could mean **RECOLOR**.

Message 4:

> There are 4 tiny letters constructed with pixels that have a color of 12-34-56.  They are located in the word HAIR (S), in the fish eye (T), in the pink shorts (A), and below the trollface (R).  They spell **"STAR"**.

Message 5:

> There is a row of black pixels in the right side of the bottom frame.  Using morse code and reading from right to left provides **CONNECTTHE**.

Message 6:

> Putting the clues together - the shape is a star or a pentagram with its points connected to form a pentagon.  So the location is **The Pentagon in Arlington County, Virginia**.

Comment: Great job you got the answer I was looking for. Although, for message 3 if you check the pixels again, the second one is 18-14-0, making C-O, R-N, E-R (and the pixels are also shaped as a corner). So, connectthe corner of theshape (star), gives you a pentagon (or a pentagon within a pentagon) which looks like the pentagon ;)

Comment: Well there is a bit but the only one related to the puzzle is the #1 to get people started. #1 leads to corner which leads to people looking for smaller things (plus clue in the corner). Other symbolism include engineers (wrench) beating pacman, making him eat too much and it was posted on twitter, where he was "pooped" on by trolls. Yeah it's kind of a stream of conscious thing, I don't even *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

You are located

> in the state of Virginia, USA

because

> at the beginning it says "I am currently bored while idly thinking about how I got this job in VA"

Comment: VA could refer to something like a job in voice acting, etc. You could be correct although after solving the puzzle there will feel like a definitive answer. The (intended) answer will be more specific and job related.